# eloquent get latest raw in join clause

Tags: join, eloquent, laravel-5, query-builder

I use laravel 5.2 I'm trying to get latest intervention of each foreing key pmt_id like bellow:

```
$res = $this->model->with('typo', 'nro', 'ctr', 'cad', 'pm')

            ->join('a2t_intervention',function ($join) use ($salar){
                    $join->on('a2t_intervention.pmt_id','=','a2t_pmt.id');
                    $join->whereRaw('a2t_intervention.pmt_id = (select max(`pmt_id`) from a2t_intervention)');
                $join->where('a2t_intervention.etat_intervention','like','nok');
                $join->whereIN('a2t_intervention.id_equipe_stt',$salar);

            });
```

but I get this ERROR : 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereRaw()

I try other ways but nothig work for me.

for each pmt_id in the table intervention we have at least one record ,I'am looking for get the last intervention foreach single pmt_id before make join with table PMT.
how to select id from table intervention in latest pmt_id like bellow in sql query:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ( SELECT pmt_id
              , MAX(id) AS id
           FROM a2t_intervention 
           WHERE etat_intervention = 'nok' 
            AND `id_equipe_stt` IN ('" . implode(',', $id_equipe_stt) . "')
         GROUP
             BY pmt_id ) AS m
INNER JOIN a2t_intervention AS t
    ON t.pmt_id = m.pmt_id
   AND t.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty self-explanatory - there is no `whereRaw` method. You could try to replace:

```
$join->whereRaw('a2t_intervention.pmt_id = (select max(`pmt_id`) from a2t_intervention)');
```

with

```
$join->where('a2t_intervention.pmt_id',  '=',  \DB::raw("(select max(`pmt_id`) from a2t_intervention)"));
```

In Later Laravel versions JoinClause extends Builder so `whereRaw` method is available but for Laravel 5.2 it isn't.

Comment: when I use your answers I get none result, and when i dont use this line i get 21 result.

Comment: How to do SELECT pmt_id
              , MAX(id) AS id
           FROM a2t_intervention  before the join.